# makefile echo $BASH_VERSION NULL

Tags: makefile, ubuntu-14.04

I have the following Makefile:

```
all:
    echo $$BASH_VERSION
```

When using make, it echoes nothing. Why? I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: is the double `$` in  the `echo $$BASH_VERSION` normal ?

Answer (score 1):

Make uses shell from [`SHELL` variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Choosing-the-Shell), its default is `/bin/sh`.

Set it to `bash` in the beginning of your makefile:

```
export SHELL := /bin/bash

all:
    @echo $$BASH_VERSION
```

Comment: run "dpkg-reconfigure dash" and select "No". This command will change default shell to bash.